# My app cannot load some images from the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, file, error-handling

I'm using Ruby on Rails on my local WEBrick server.

I'm generating some images of websites from urls, writing them to my local filesystem, and displaying them. I name the images by their url but replace all `\` with `-`. Some images seem to not be loading because it cannot find the images on my filesystem, and I get the broken image icon. However, I see that all the images are there when I check my filesystem.

This is the error I get in my logs:

```
Started GET "/images/image_site/http:--www.urbandictionary.com-define.php?term=slim%20shady.jpg?1309465379" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Jun 30 13:23:06 -0700 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/images/image_site/http:--www.urbandictionary.com-define.php"):
```

This is my html code:

```
<img alt="Http:--www.urbandictionary.com-define.php?term=slim%20shady" class="site_image" src="/images/image_site/http:--www.urbandictionary.com-define.php?term=slim%20shady.jpg?1309465379">
```

What going on and how can I fix this? Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're not properly encoding your image names in the `src` attribute. I'd guess that you have a file with a name like this:

```
http:--www.urbandictionary.com-define.php?term=slim%20shady.jpg
```

But when you have this:

```
src="/images/image_site/http:--www.urbandictionary.com-define.php?term=slim%20shady.jpg?1309465379"
```

The filename looks like this:

```
/images/image_site/http:--www.urbandictionary.com-define.php
```

because everything after the first `?` is considered to be part of the query string.

Replacing the slashes with hyphens is not good enough, you're still leaving all sorts of holes for confusion and nefarious intent. Instead, you should generate the image file names completely, something like `id.jpg` where `id` is the image's ID in your database. Then, store the original filename in your database and only show that filename (properly encoded!) to people, don't use it in your local file system.

A quick fix would be to properly URL encode your `src` attributes. But you really should fix up how you handle the images or you will leave yourself open to all sorts of trouble.

Comment: I'm having trouble with figuring out the "quick fix". What about `<img alt="Http:--www.last.fm-music-eminem-_-the+real+slim+shady" class="site_image" src="/images/image_site/http:--www.last.fm-music-Eminem-_-The+Real+Slim+Shady.jpg?1309473638">`? That doesn't have a query string in the url. `Started GET "/images/image_site/http:--www.last.fm-music-Eminem-_-The+Real+Slim+Shady.jpg?1309473638" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Jun 30 15:45:40 -0700 2011`

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/images/image_site/http:--www.last.fm-music-Eminem-_-The+Real+Slim+Shady.jpg"):`

Comment: I switched to escaping the urls but now none of the urls are found. Here's an example: `Started GET "/images/image_site/http%3A%2F%2Fmusic.aol.com%2Falbum%2Feminem%2Fthe-slim-shady-lp%2F346579.jpg?1309475967" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Jun 30 16:20:00 -0700 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/images/image_site/http%3A%2F%2Fmusic.aol.com%2Falbum%2Feminem%2Fthe-slim-shady-lp%2F346579.jpg"):` Once again, the files are there...

Comment: @Justin: a `+` in a URL is translated [to a space in a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464885/rails-plus-sign-in-get-request-replaced-by-space/6464940#6464940). What route are you using for the images?

Comment: sorry what do you mean by route (other than directing incoming requests to controllers)? there is no `+` in the second path I posted...

Comment: @Justin: `%3A` is a colon, `%2F` is a slash. Looks like you're encoding the names with slashes rather than the names that you've applied your "slash to hyphen" mangling to.

Comment: @Justin: Sigh, I think Rails (3.1 at least) is trying to be too clever for its own good. When I try to get a file called `that+that.jpg` using `this%2Bthat.jpg` I get a "File not found: /images/this that.jpg" error so it looks like something somewhere is decoding the `%2B` (correctly) to `+` and then something somewhere is (incorrectly) decoding that again to a single space. So, I guess your quick fix is going to have to translate `+` to `-` as well as `/` to `-` in both the file names and the URLs. Probably best to ditch the quick fix and rework it completely as I outlined in my answer.

Comment: oh haha ok I'll try that out, dam Rails :P

Comment: I'm still interested in the quick fix though. How exactly can I solve this? The `+` to `-` didn't work. I also tried `%` to `-`. Didn't work.

Comment: @Justin: Ditch the quick fix and do it properly, sounds like it will be faster and less error prone (as is often the case).

Answer (score -1):

You need to place images in your `public/` folder and then you can access them from there.  By default Rails will server static assets primarily from `public/`.

Comment: my images are in my `/public` folder